# Unix Sed Command to replace file name entries in a *.txt file

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have a class.txt file which contains multiple .class file entries along with their respective paths, I want to rename .class file names as mentioned

Requirement:

from

```
modules/abc_1.1.3/abc.domain.ear!/APP-INF/lib/adj.jar!/ba/sr/ApplicationModule.class
```

to:

```
modules/abc_1.1.3/abc.domain.ear!/APP-INF/lib/adj.jar!/ba/sr/[ApplicationModule\$.*\.class]
```

I tried using sed command, but didnt get desired output as shown below

```
cat class.txt | sed "s/.class/\\\\$.*\\\.class]/g"

modules/abc_1.1.3/abc.domain.ear!/APP-INF/lib/adj.jar!/ba/sr/ApplicationModule\$.*\.class]
```

Kindly help, Thanks!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com will answer you

Comment: @Faizan What has this got to do with Ubuntu?!

Comment: @biffen ask Ubuntu has many bash programmers like SO has many programmers.

Comment: @Faizan askubuntu.com is for *Ubuntu-related* questions, which this is not. Although it wouldn't be off-topic per se there, it is very much on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to capture file name:

```
sed 's/\([^/]*\).class/[\1\\$.*\\.class]/g'
```

Comment: Works, but messy: use single quotes: `sed 's/\([^/]*\).class/[\1\\$.*\\.class]/g'` -- regex chars do not need escaping in the replacement part

Answer (score 0):

You need to use capture groups in order to capture the filename and its extension in two separate groups.

```
$ sed 's~\([^./]*\)\.\([^/.]*\)$~[\1\\\$.*\\.\2]~' file
modules/abc_1.1.3/abc.domain.ear!/APP-INF/lib/adj.jar!/ba/sr/[ApplicationModule\$.*\.class]
```